GridDB Error Code: GS_HOME, GS_LOG environment variable not set
I am attempting to configure an administrator user on GridDB using the following command:
gs_passwd admin

However, I encountered the following error: "A00105: GS_HOME, GS_LOG environment variable not set."
I am using a WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) machine, and my GridDB version is "5.1.0-39692 CE."
In response to this issue, I've checked to ensure that the GridDB installation directory is correctly set in the GS_HOME environment variable. Also,  have verified to ensure the GS_LOG environment variable is set to the path where GridDB logs are stored after which I ran gs_passwd admin command again to configure the administrator user but still encountered the "A00105: GS_HOME, GS_LOG environment variable not set" error.
I am seeking assistance on how to effectively resolve the "A00105: GS_HOME, GS_LOG environment variable not set" error.
Are there any environment variables that still needs to be configured or any setup provisions required to establish an administrator user on GridDB?

I’ve got the same error while trying to run the gs_stat command. I was able to find a workaround that also works with  gs_passwd, as follows:

Find the location where  GridDB was installed by running  $ dpkg -L griddb. In my case, the installation files are located in /usr/griddb-5.5.0.
$ dpkg -L griddb


In my system, gridDB was installed on /usr/griddb-5.5.0

Find the location of GridDB log files. You can determine that by running gs_sh and looking for the first message, which shows the gridstore location.
gs_sh


In my case, logs files are located on /var/lib/gridstore/log :
$ ls /var/lib/gridstore/log/


Switch to root:
$ sudo su –

Set environment variables GS_HOME and GS_LOG to point to the right directories:
export GS_HOME=/usr/griddb-5.5.0
export GS_LOG=/var/lib/gridstore/log

You should be able to run gs_passwd now, without getting that error:
gs_passwd admin -p admin


